# SLDS Button refreshing entire page on click in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, button

I am just after a simple button icon to indicate a warning. I need it to pop up a tooltip on click of the errors.

So I found `<lightning-button-icon>` which was just about what I needed. The issue, though, is that I can't change the color due to new CSS rules with LWCs. I need to to be a red color for error. (this honestly surprises me that they still haven't added a color parameter to their various button components and instead force you to use their default gray...).

So then I moved onto a button that will just use slds:

```
<button class="warning-button slds-button slds-button_icon" onclick={warningButtonClick}>
    <svg class={buttonSizeClass} aria-hidden="true" style={buttonColorStyle}>
        <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#warning"></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Cool, my button now looks exactly like the `lightning-button-icon` AND I get the color I want. Of course that couldn't just be the end of it... On click, it refreshes my entire Visualforce page...

How do you stop/prevent this refresh from happening?

This is a button that is an LWC that is inside an LWC, that is then inside a Visualforce page (hosted in a lightning component so it can be on a Visualforce page).

Comment: kinda hard to tell without seeing what your lwc does and how it interacts with the VF page

Comment: It doesn't interact. It's just there. It is an old VF page so kind of stuck with it for now, I just want an LWC on it so it has to be in an aura component. And the LWC is doing nothing but displaying a button. And I want my onclick to happen when it is clicked, not refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO the button tag needs a type tag `type="button"` or else it will just submit the entire page which is its default behaviour.

Comment: Ah yes, this worked, thanks!. Nice easy fix.